# Cog VM and indirect variable access

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak

Does anyone know whether the Cog VM for Pharo and Squeak is able to optimize away simple indirect variable accesses with accessors like this:

```
SomeClass>>someProperty
    ^ someProperty
SomeClass>>someSecondProperty
    ^ someSecondProperty
```

that just return an instance variable, so that methods like this:

```
SomeClass>>someMethod
    ^ self someProperty doWith: self someSecondProperty
```

will be no slower than methods like this:

```
SomeClass>>someMethod
    ^ someProperty doWith: someSecondProperty
```

I did some benchmarks, and they do seem roughly equivalent in speed, but I'm curious if anyone familiar with Cog knows for certain, because if there is a difference (no matter how slight), then there might be situations however rare where one is inappropriate.

Comment: The Pharo User Group & mailing list may also be an appropriate place to ask. There is much activity.

Comment: Yeap this question should be directed to the pharo-dev mailing list and cog mailing list where Eliot whos behind Cog can answer in detail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a little cost right now but it's so little that you should not bother. If you want performance, you are willing to change other parts of your code, not instance variable access.

A quick bench:
bench 
    ^ { [ iv yourself ] bench . [ self iv yourself ] bench }
=> #('52,400,000 per second.' '49,800,000 per second.')
The difference does not look so big.

Once jitted and executed once, the difference is that "self iv" executes an inline cache check, a cpu call and a cpu return in addition of fetching the instance variable value. The call and return instructions are most probably going to be anticipated by the cpu and not really executed. So it's about the inline cache check which is a very cheap operation.

What the inlining compiler in development will add is that the cpu call and return are really going to be removed with inlining, which will cover the cases where the cpu has not anticipated them. In addition, the inline cache check may or may not be removed depending on circumstances.

There are details such as the getter method needs to be compiled to native code which takes room in the machine code zone which could increase the number of machine code zone garbage collection, but that's even more anecdotic than the inline cache check overhead.

So in short, there is a very very very little overhead right now but that overhead will decrease in the future.

Clement

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough question... And I don't know the exact answer. But I can help you learning how to check by yourself with a few clues.

You'll need to load the VMMaker package in an image. In Pharo, there is a procedure to build such image by just downloading everything from the net and github. See https://github.com/pharo-project/pharo-vm

Then the main hint is that methods that just return an instance variable are compiled as if executing primitive 264 + inst var offset... (for example, you'll see this by inspecting `Interval>>#first` or any other simple inst var getter)

In classical interpreter VM, this is handled in `Interpreter>>internalExecuteNewMethod`.
It seems like you pay the cost of a method lookup (some caches make this cheaper), but not of a real method activation.
I suppose that it explains that debuggers can't enter into such simple methods... This however is not a real inlining.

In COG, the same happens in `StackInterpreter>>internalQuickPrimitiveResponse` if ever interpreter is used.

As for the JIT, this is handled by `Cogit>>compilePrimitive`, see also implementors of `genQuickReturnInstVar`. This is not proper inlining either, but you can see that there are very few instructions generated. Again, I bet you generally don't pay the price of a lookup thank to so called Polymorphic Inline Cache (PIC).

For real inlining, I didn't find a clue after this quick browsing of source code...
My understanding is that it will happen at image side thru callback from Sista VM, but this is work in progress and only my vague recollection. Clement Bera is writing a blog about this (the sista chronicles at http://clementbera.wordpress.com)

If you're afraid of digging in VMMaker source code, I invite you to ask on vm-dev.lists.squeakfoundation.org I'm pretty sure Eliot Miranda or Clement will be happy to give you a far more accurate answer.

**EDIT**

I forgot to tell you about the conclusion of above perigrinations: I think that there will be a very small difference if you directly use the inst. var. rather than a getter, but this shouldn't be really noticeable, and in all cases, your programming style should NOT be guided by such neglectable optimizations.

Comment: I think the compiler can't really optimize =self someProperty= because subclasses might override this method and the compiler cannot know all subclasses at compile time. There is also the notion of "quick" methods. Send #isQuick to a CompiledMethod and look at the senders of this message.

Comment: @DamienCassou yes, quick methods are those marked as if sending a quick primitive though there is no <primitive ...> in source, and all my answer is about the machinery involved in the VM to handle them undercover... The case of override is handled by PIC in the VM too, and that's why inlining is so involved. So handling inlining in image with a higher level language, but only at hot spot detected by the VM is not a bad choice.